# Similar Object are different using VueJs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm using the following getter in my Vuex store to get the datasets from my state.

```
getDatasets: state => {
    let datasets = [];
    state.observations.forEach(obs => {
      if (!datasets.includes(obs.dataset)) {
        datasets.push(obs.dataset);
      }
    })
    return datasets;
  }
```

However, this return as many datasets as observations in my state whereas it should return only one dataset.

I believe this is due to the `__obs__` field added by VueJs that is different for each dataset object.

Did I misunderstood something and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the issue with vuex/vue. By checking `datasets.includes(obs.dataset))`, you are actually check if `datasets` contains any object that have same reference with `obs.dataset`, which is inevitably false.

A very simple example can be ran in browser console to replicate your logic:

```
var state = { observations: [ { dataset: {}}, { dataset: {}} ]}
var datasets = []
state.observations.forEach(function(obs) {
    if (!datasets.includes(obs.dataset)) {
        datasets.push(obs.dataset);
    }
})
console.log(datasets.length) // 2, not 1
console.log(datasets[0] === state.observations[0].dataset) // true, same reference
console.log(datasets[0] === state.observations[1].dataset) // false
```

If you want to get unique values of datasets, try comparing parsed string of object instead:

```
state.observations.forEach(obs => {
    if (!datasets.some(
        elem => SON.stringify(elem) === JSON.stringify(obs.dataset))
    ) {
        datasets.push(obs.dataset);
    }
})
```